How to use EAS secrets in Expo(React-Native) Project?
I'm developing a mobile app using Expo and React Native. To use push notifications, I've copied the google-services.json file to /android/app/google-services.json. I also added "googleServicesFile": "./android/app/google-services.json" to the app.json file.
However, when I run the "eas build -> Android" command, I encounter the following error:
"google-services.json" is missing, make sure that the file exists. Remember that EAS Build only uploads the files tracked by git. Use EAS secrets to provide EAS Build with the file.

I found some guidance online that suggests using EAS secrets (https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/#how-to-upload-a-secret-file-and-use-it-in-my-app-config). The article advises adding EAS secrets. And add "googleServicesFile: process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON" in the app.config.js file.
I have added EAS secrets, but my Expo project does not have an app.config.js file. (I created the project using the "npx create-expo-app" command.)
How can I use EAS secrets without an app.config.js file?"

The documentations on Expo is crap confusing. I encountered the same situation like yours. I also struggled with the Google Authentication with Expo. It seems obsolete and did not provide better explanation.
The easiest way to fix is to use .easignore, simply copy all the contents from .gitignore except your google-services.json. The rationale is that EAS Build will ignore the file on .gitignore but at the same time you don't want to upload your credentials to Github. So by using .easignore, it will take precendence over .gitignore when it comes to EAS Build and it allows your google-services.json to be included in the build.
From my understanding, app.config is equivalent to app.json file, someone please correct me if i am wrong.
Hopefully this could help you.
